# Generic Context Menu for multiple controls in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF window with 4 read-only `TextBoxes` in it, to all of which I need to enable a context menu with copy option. Currently I'm doing with code behind. But I heard it is not a good approach.

```
<TextBox Name="StepsTextBox" 
         Text="{Binding Steps, Mode=OneWay}" 
         IsReadOnly="True" 
         Click="Copy_click"/>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
private void Copy_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StepsTextBox.Copy();
}
```

I tried using MVVM as follows:

```
<TextBox.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Copy" Command="{Binding OnCopyButtonClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=StepsTextBox}"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</TextBox.ContextMenu>
```

But how do I access this text box from the code if I pass it as parameter. And also how can I keep this code generic for all the textboxes?. Could anyone help?. Thanks in advance.

```
private void OnCopyButtonClick(TextBox textBox)
{
    //??
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the build-in [ApplicationCommands.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.copy(v=vs.110).aspx). No need to implement anything, the copy functionality is already implemented.

```
<TextBox.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Copy" Command="Copy" />
    </ContextMenu>
</TextBox.ContextMenu>
```

You will still have to select the text before copying it, but that's to be expected when copying text.